# Auditing configuration

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, linux-audit

I'm trying to set up filesystem auditing using `auditd` on Ubuntu 12.04.5. I have a filesystem being exported, call it `/exports/data`, that I need audited. I have the following rule in place:

```
LIST_RULES: exit,always dir=/exports/data (0x14) perm=wa
```

Anytime I do anything in that directory on the NFS server, an audit event gets logged normally. Anytime I do anything on an NFS client, nothing gets logged. What rule do I need to put in place / syscall do I need to watch to audit NFS events?

Answer (score 1):

The `auditd` subsystem watches system calls, and the NFS clients are making system calls on their respective hosts. (So `auditd` cannot detect system calls on hosts other than itself.)

To monitor the events of the clients, configure `auditd` on the remote hosts. Use the `audisp-remote` plugin on these hosts to send audit-related messages to a central logging host that uses the `audispd` syslog plugin. Then the audit logs will be available in one aggregated location.

From the manual on `audisp-remote`:

> audisp-remote is a plugin for the audit event dispatcher daemon, audispd, that preforms remote logging to an aggregate logging server.

Comment: Does the NFS server not make syscalls on behalf of the client to actually read/write files?

Comment: There are many kernel subsystems that generate security log data which are, at the moment, ignored by auditd. (It would be nice if these subsystems were extended.)